# Unable to run bash commands in php script

Tags: php, bash, bluehost

I'm trying to use a script to automate some syncing stuff with the website's corresponding github.

The offending code is

```
 <html>
    <head><title>github_sync script</title></head>
    <body><p>Github sync script working... Although you're probably a github webhook anyways</p><body>

<?php
    `mkdir test_dir`;
    `cd github_sync/`;
    `git clone https://github.com/frczyxw/my-website.git`;
    `cd my-website/`;
    `rm sixdegrees/`;
    `cp -R * ../../`;
?>
</html>
```

The script is placed in the public_html/beta/directory. I can log into and navigate through the ftp and launch the script by clicking on it fine (the body text displays), but upon rechecking the ftp directory, I find that `public_html/beta/test_dir` has not appeared, nor does `/public_html/beta/github_sync/` have anything in it (I created it manually previous to running the script).

The server should be running php5.3, and I am hosting the website vie Bluehost

Comment: PHP is not ShellScript.

Comment: My assumption is that Bluehost disables the `shell_exec()` command, which in turn disables the backtick operator. What does the output of `ini_get('disable_functions')` give you?

Comment: Well, you got one thing right. PHP is offensive! </joke>

Comment: @scopey This will sound really dumb, but how do I do what you say? I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu- I just inserted a `print("hello");` command for testing purposes, and i dont know where I would find that output

Comment: `echo '<pre>'; var_dump(ini_get('disable_functions')); exit;`

Comment: But where would I view this output? EDIT: Right, should be displayed on the screen if what little I know of php serves me accurately

Comment: Look at the sky. It will be printed in the moon.

Comment: Access the file with your browser, or run it on the command line of your server. How are you running your script? How would you see that HTML that you have written?

Comment: I'm just clicking on the file in my browser. The code that you gave me just results in "'; var_dump(ini_get('disable_functions'));" being displayed on screen

Comment: Put it within `<?php ?>` tags

Comment: When I ssh into the directory from my own command line and run the script the output of init_get("diable_functions") seems to be empty

Comment: Also, it looks like "cd" isnt working, nor is just clicking on the script from the ftp browser client actually launching it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I've solved the problem-

The server was configured correctly- however it turns out that to run all of these commands in sequence and in the same context (i.e. cd into github_sync make a git clone in that folder) the commands need to be executed all at once, like

```
`cd github_sync/;git clone wsgzsgg; rm -rf...`
```

Thnaks to everyone who tried to help